# Hiding rows with Power BI Desktop (Report Server)

Tags: powerbi

how can I solve this?

I have a table with a bunch of lot numbers, country information ... Here I count the rows for each lot when filters are used. Depending on the filters lots can disappear.
So far so simple.

Now I need only the information of x lots before and behind when a lot number is selected. It's quite easy to filter on the selected lot. But I have no idea how i can focus on the x rows before/behind the selected lot.

I tried a measure with RANKX, but this will not work since lot numbers aren't unique.

Maybe it is possible to use row numbers, index or something else on the filtered data?

[Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI5k6.png)

Please give me a hint.

I just grouped my table by lot number and added an index with query editor

[Initial indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5NAh.png)

So it would be easy to get x rows before/behind.

[Index after filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMV8w.png)

But using filters will make that idea to be a bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with my first row I wanna show in the visual having an unique row identifier, e.g. an id.
With the count of rows I used TOPN to get the identifier of  the last row. I used that approach because in most cases the identifier isn't in a row. Since the shown rows are aggregated I used following measure to determine the last index:

```
IndexLast = 

var _size = SELECTEDVALUE(ShowRows[Val])      -- how many rows 
var _indexStart = SELECTEDVALUE(Index[Start]) -- starting index
var _cluster = GROUPBY(Filter(ALLSELECTED(Table1), Table1[Index] > _indexStart), [Index])  -- group all indexes behind starting index
var _tops = topn(_size, _cluster, [Index], asc)  -- get so many rows you need

return
    maxx(Allselected(Table1), Table1[Index])
```

Measure for first row:

```
IndexFirst = SELECTEDVALUE(Index[Start]) -- starting index
```

Now I added a measure to the table to indicate whiche rows are visible or not

```
_visible = 

var _currentIndex = max(Table1[Index])
var _Min = DummyTable[IndexFirst]
var _Max = DummyTable[IndexLast]

return
    if (_currentIndex >= _Min && _currentIndex <= _Max, 1)
```

At the end used that measure as filter for my visual
[Visual filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVLaf.png)

So I am now able to steer which rows are visible or not .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).